# Dimensionality of a Diagonal Subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. If $\Delta = \{(\textbf{v},\textbf{v})| \textbf{v} \in V\}$ is the diagonal subspace of $V\times V$, show that dim$\Delta$ = dim$V$.

I know this following theorem: Let $W$ be a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Then dim$W$ = dim $V$ if and only if $W=V$.

Then according to this theorem, doesn't it necessarily follow that if I can assume that dim$\Delta$ = dim$V$ is true, then $\Delta = V$ is true since it can be shown that $\Delta$ is a subspace of $V$ (or is that not true?)? But how can $\Delta = V$ if $\Delta$ is made up of tuples of vectors in $V$? For example, if vector $\textbf{v} = (1,1) \in V$, then $(\textbf{v},\textbf{v}) = ( (1,1), (1,1) ) \in \Delta$, but $( (1,1), (1,1) ) \notin V$. Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of $\Delta$, it is a subspace of $V\times V$ but not $V$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Delta$ is not a subspace of $V$. it is a subspace of $V \times V$ so the result you are quoting is not applicable here.